# Comparing AUCs of ROC of same diagnostic test on different samples

Tags: roc, auc

Supposed I've got a sample of 200 subjects, and based on these subjects, I determined the AUC of the ROC of a diagnostic test. Next, from these 200 subjects, I drew a subsample of the diagnostic test's output (n=150). No new mathematical model was created based on raw input of the subsamples. On this subsample, I calculated another AUC of the subgroup's ROC.

I would like to determine if the subgroup gives a significantly different performance compared to the whole dataset. I have read about the DeLong's test of equality and understand that it compares 2 different diagnostic tests applied to the same sample, so it might not be applicable to my analysis.

What test could I perform to compare the subset's AUC to that from the full set (derived from the same model)?

Comment: 'What test could I perform to compare the AUCs derived from the same diagnostic test applied to different samples?' is not representative of your situation. It should be : What test could I perform to compare the AUCs derived from the same diagnostic test applied to a  subset of the samples used for the other model? One important question is whether the second set of scores is using the same model or was a new model derived on the subset?

Comment: Hi @ReneBt thanks for replying. It is using the same model.

Comment: It is unclear what the motive is for such a question. Perhaps you want to use bootstrap to find confidence intervals, perhaps you want to eliminate outliers, but without knowing why this question arose, it makes it hard to give advice.